# how to estimate HIVE SQL query complexity?

Tags: sql, hive, query-optimization

With Map Reduce paradigm (through TEZ or MR), I think it is very complex to estimate an HIVE query complexity, especially when it is made of many joins (LEFT and INNER).

While an explain in MySQL or ORACLE is very explicit about a lake of index or key use, an explain in Hive is far more cloudy.

Some queries involve a big cpu / memory occupation and take a lot of time and it is hard for me to locate these points and when the same query take 600 seconds one day and 120 the next day, it becomes insane :)

Helps and advices and XP sharing will be very appreciated !

Comment: That question is "insanely" generic, biloute... What file format(s) are you using? What is the typical data file/block size? What are your MR/TEZ container sizes (AM, Map, Reduce)? Do you use Hive statistics? Which version of Hive, by the way?

Comment: Speaking about Oracle -- I have seen too many Prod emergencies because of an execution plan instability, with a much larger impact than x5 in execution time. And too many databases where most of the ETL time window was used for full statistics recomputation, because people were scared as hell about a rogue exec plan change. And too many queries stuffed with legacy "hints", to force the exec plan. Insanity is not specific to the Hadoop world.

Comment: _"Hive query ... made of many joins"_ >> looks like you are looking for trouble; a number of companies are using commercial MPP databases such as Vertica (cf. Critéo) or Exasol on top of Hadoop, simply because Hive is not good at joins, nor at concurrent executions, etc.

Comment: I admit the generic aspect of that question :) Sorry for that ;-)

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot for your replies. I am using ORC file format, no Hive statistics, 25MB file size... Tell me why Hive isn't good at joins ? I use TEZ engine to compute joins because this seems to be a join-optimized implementation of MR, am I wrong ? I don't have a great XP about that...

Comment: I work in batch mode with Hive (honestly, I don't see how it can be used otherwise), so your advice is to avoid join and to build temporary tables or something else ?

Comment: Quoting Curt Monash, _"distributed join performance is a particular challenge"_ (and he was not refering to Hive) http://www.dbms2.com/2014/03/28/nosql-vs-newsql-vs-traditional-rdbms/ >> also in http://www.dbms2.com/2011/07/14/an-odd-claim-attributed-to-mike-stonebraker/ >> and a post (about MemSQL) detailing different distributed join algorithms http://www.dbms2.com/2015/05/20/memsql-4-0/

Comment: There is some literature about the different ways Hive can run a JOIN *(one at a time)*. TEZ may limit the number of intermediate I/O operations, by re-using intermediate results in memory; but even then, big JOINs won't work out of the box. You have to understand how JOINs work, cf. http://www.openkb.info/2014/11/understanding-hive-joins-in-explain.html for example, understand how your input file format & fragmentation & compression changes the equation, how much skew you have in your data, how you can tweak container size / container number, etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices and references, I am on it ;)